# ps command shows bogus child processes

Tags: shell, unix, process, ksh, ps

I've encountered a funny problem on unix systems (tested on SunOS and AIX): I execute a script and want to list itself (using `ps`) - sometimes ps displays two, additional child processes of the script, sometimes its only one extra child process and most of the time the output correctly shows a single process. I've found a thread here [Multiple processes with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145318/multiple-processes-with-the-same-name) but my case is different.

Consider a script named `test.sh` as the one below:

```
#!/bin/ksh
echo before $$
ps -f | grep test.sh | grep -v grep
echo after $$
```

It's very simple - it shows its PID, then finds itself (and such like) on the process list and only filters out the grep command (just in case).
Now, I'm going to execute a very simple routine in shell:

```
while [ 1 -eq 1 ]; do test.sh; done
```

Just an infinite loop executing `test.sh` one by one. What I get in the output? See below:

```
before 20990
  user   20990 14993   0 08:54:06 pts/5       0:00 /bin/ksh test.sh
after 20990
before 20994
  user   20994 14993   0 08:54:06 pts/5       0:00 /bin/ksh test.sh
after 20994
before 20998
  user   21001 20998   0 08:54:06 pts/5       0:00 /bin/ksh test.sh
  user   21000 20998   0 08:54:06 pts/5       0:00 /bin/ksh test.sh
  user   20998 14993   0 08:54:06 pts/5       0:00 /bin/ksh test.sh
after 20998
before 21002
  user   21002 14993   0 08:54:06 pts/5       0:00 /bin/ksh test.sh
after 21002
before 21006
  user   21006 14993   0 08:54:07 pts/5       0:00 /bin/ksh test.sh
after 21006
```

**Can anyone explain to me what are the processes 21001 and 21000? they are not forked, since there are no traces "before/after" for them. This happens only occasionally...**

This is not much of a problem for me but I'm curious to know what happens here and what to expect in more complex cases.

Let's say I want to allow my script's execution only if there are no other sessions of this script executed. I will then use ps and filter the "test.sh" + filter out all the lines with my PID - here, the script will filter out itself + its children, which is good, but that's just workaround to an issue that I don't really understand. Hence this thread :)

I didn't play with fetching the actual data stored in /proc, since I don't know the filesystem's structure on Sun or AIX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These extra processes are the subshells about to process the first two pipeline components.

This is confirmed with running a dtrace script showing all exec calls:

```
before 3929
    root  3929  1630   0 10:36:03 pts/3       0:00 /bin/ksh ./test.sh
    root  3932  3929   0 10:36:03 pts/3       0:00 /bin/ksh ./test.sh
    root  3931  3929   0 10:36:03 pts/3       0:00 /bin/ksh ./test.sh
after 3929
```

dtrace output for these processes:

```
2013 Sep  5 10:36:02 3929 /bin/ksh ./test.sh
2013 Sep  5 10:36:02 3931 grep test.sh
2013 Sep  5 10:36:02 3932 grep -v grep
```

The fact `/bin/ksh ./test.sh` is displayed instead of the actual command run is `argv[0]` has not been updated yet. It will be replaced only after the exec call has completed.

Just after a fork, both the parent and child process share the same argument list. The only difference is the process ID. This is what you are observing.

Comment: That's quite helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I'm only confused about the output. I've taken your point into consideration and modified my script to execute only `ps -f | grep test.sh` (without `grep -v grep`).
Why on earth almost everytime it shows `grep test.sh` in the output and sometimes I see `/bin/ksh test.sh`? Can you also explain that? I would be grateful.

Regards.